# what does 한 몫 한거 같기도 mean?

Tags: vocabulary

순위대로 노래를 픽하는 이전 시즌의 시스템을 그대로 차용했다면, 마지막까지 남았던 곡이기에 꽤 기피되었던 곡이라 볼 수 있는데(일본어 버전이었던게 한연생들 입장에선 한 몫 한거 같기도?)

[link](http://mlbpark.donga.com/mp/b.php?p=1&b=bullpen&id=201807170020558900&select=&query=&user=&site=&reply=&source=&sig=h4a9GY2Y6h9RKfX@hlj9Sl-g5mlq)

Answer (score 1):

순위대로 노래를 픽(pick)하는 이전 시즌의 시스템을 그대로 차용했다면, 마지막까지 남았던 곡

I can not judge that this sentence is gramatically correct. Let me translate directly : If we use the system used in last year whose participator can have preferece at choosing one in selected songs, then the song was not choosed until the end.

At any rate, we can grasp the meaning of talker.

이기에 꽤 기피되었던 곡이라 볼 수 있는데(일본어 버전이었던게 한연생들 입장에선 한 몫 한거 같기도?) 하위권의 반란이라고 해도 손색이 없을 정도로 우수한 무대를 선보였다고 생각.

몫 means a role or profit.

일본어 버전이었던게 한연생들 입장에선 한 몫 한것 같다 : It seems that to 한연생(Korean song student?), the fact that the sone is Japan version plays a role.

(Maybe, they are Japanese)

니 몫(할당량)은 해야지 : You must play a role given to you.

니 몫은 니가 챙겨야지 : You must care your money.